# How to access variables from class using static methods?

Tags: javascript

```
//my class
function myClass()
{
   this.pubVar = 'hello public';
   var priVar = 'hello private';


}

myClass.staticMethod = function()
{

   //how do i access thos variables here

}
```

I tried `alert(this.pubVar)` and `alert(priVar)` with no success. What am I doing wrong?

I'm going to change the question a bit.. I didn't explain it well the first time through.

How do I declare static variables in a class?

I know with java it's simple, you just put static infront of the variable type and presto you've got a static variable. I can't seem to find that option for javascript..

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to use the instance of the object inside of your method, I think that you are not really wanting to create a *static method*, what you want, is a method that is applicable and accessible by all the instances.

For doing that you can extend the constructor's [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError/prototype):

```
function MyClass() {
   this.pubVar = 'hello public';
   var priVar = 'hello private';
}

MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
   alert(this.pubVar);
}


var instance = new MyClass();
instance.myMethod(); // alerts 'hello public'
```

When you extend the prototype of a constructor function, all the members that reside on it, will be inherited to the object instances created with the [new](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/new_Operator) operator.

So you define this method only once in your constructor function, and it will be accessible in the context of each instance (the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator) keyword inside the method refers to the object instance).

Comment: This is what I was gonna say. +1/

Answer (score 3):

Definition:

```
myClass.staticMethod = function(obj)
{
    alert(obj.pubVar);
}
```

Use:

```
var instance = new myClass();
myClass.staticMethod(instance);
```

You won't be able to use "priVar", since it isn't a variable on the class. It's a method-scoped variable.

Also, if you need to access properties of the class, why are you making it a static method?

Comment: I didn't really want to create a instance, I like calling a function by the classname.methodname()

Comment: Then you definitely don't want to use a static method.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... If you are trying to access "this" then you don't really want a static method. A static method belongs to the class and doesn't have access to any given instance of that class, and therefore "this" does not exist in the context of a static method.

If you are looking for the code for an instance method it would be something along these lines:

```
function myClass()
{
    this.pubVar = 'hello public';
    var priVar = 'hello private';

    this.method = function(){
        alert(priVar);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass a reference to an object into your static method, which would look something like this:

```
function myClass()
{
    this.pubVar = 'hello public';
    var priVar = 'hello private';
}
myClass.staticMethod = function(obj)
{
    alert(obj.pubVar);
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: so I guess the answer is no... I was trying to access it from the class so I didn't have to pass it through to every static method

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the answer on a old post, may be this will help someone

If you want to access a variable from a static method, you can declare that variable as a static property.

```
//my class
function myClass()
{
   this.pubVar = 'hello public';
   var priVar = 'hello private';
}

myClass.staticProperty = 'someValue';

myClass.staticMethod = function()
{
    //This is how you access it
    alert(myClass.staticProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple. Of cause you need an instance of class for this purpose:

```
//my class
function myClass()
{
   this.pubVar = 'hello public';
   var priVar = 'hello private';
}

myClass.staticMethod = function()
{
   //how do i access thos variables here
   alert(this.pubVar);
}

var instance=new myClass(); // this is instance of class
myClass.staticMethod.call(instance)
```

The only question do you really need to use static then?
Also there are no means to access priVar. Because it uses closure.

Comment: I thought in java that you could declare static variables in a class and access them using static methods.

Comment: I guess the question should have been how to declare static variables in javascript class..